# Android studio:java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry

Tags: android-studio

I´m working on my project and found this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: lejos/internal/io/package-info.class

I tried gradlew clean, but it didn´t work.  Here is my app.build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kony.ev3remotecontrol"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
   }

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Which jars are you using?

Comment: These ones:
commons-cli, dbusjava, ev3classes, ev3tools, jcommon, jfreechart, jsch-0.1.50 and opencv-2411

Comment: I figured out. It was really redundant some of those jars.Ev3classes.jar is enough for my project. Thank yo ufor your time Gabrielle